# Java function which only takes JPA entities as parameter

Tags: java, jpa

Is it is possible to create a function which only takes classes, which have been marked with the `@Entity` tag as parameter?

The function should be compile time typesafe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compell a method with specific annotation to have specific parameters/signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798279/compell-a-method-with-specific-annotation-to-have-specific-parameters-signature)

Comment: You could also just create a marker `interface` and let all your entities extend it and then the method accepts only instances of that `interface` as parameters.

Comment: Why don't you just receive Class type, on which your @Entity is set on?

Comment: the way I see, Its lots of reflection and configuration